# Appending Binary files

Tags: c++, file-io

I have to write numerical data to binary files. Since some of the data vectors I deal with can be several gigs in size, I have learned not to use C++ iostreams. Instead I want to use C File*.  I'm running into a problem right off the bat where I need to write some meta data to the front of the binary file. Since some of the meta data is not known at first I need to append the meta data as I get it to the appropriate offsets in the file.

for example lets say I have to enter a uint16_t representation for the year, month , and day, but first I need to skip the first entry(a uint32_t value for precision);

I don't know what i'm doing wrong but I can't seem to append  the file with "ab".
Here's an example of what I wrote:

```
#include<cstdio>

uint16_t year = 2001;
uint16_t month = 8;
uint16_t day = 23;

uint16_t dateArray[]={year , month, day};

File * fileStream;
fileStream = fopen("/Users/mmmmmm/Desktop/test.bin" , "wb");

if(fileStream){

// skip the first 4 bytes
fseek ( fileStream , 4 , SEEK_SET );

fwrite(dateArray, sizeof(dateArray[0]) ,( sizeof(dateArray) / sizeof(dateArray[0]) ), filestream);

fclose(filestream);

}
 // loops and other code to prepare and gather other parameters
```

// now append the front of the file with the precision.

```
uint32_t precision = 32;

File *fileStream2;
fileStream2 = fopen("/Users/mmmmmm/Desktop/test.bin" , "ab"); 

if(fileStream2){

// Get to the top of the file
rewind(fileStream2);

fwrite(&precision, sizeof(precision) , 1 , fileStream2);

fclose(fileStream2);

}
```

The appended data does not write. If I change it to "wb", then the file overwrites. I was able to get it to work with "r+b", but I don't understand why. I thought "ab" would be proper. Also , should I be using buffers or is this a sufficient approach?

Thanks for the advise

BTW this is on MacOSX

Comment: Why have you chosen not to use `iostream`

Comment: You can append only to the end of file

Comment: @Cole Johnson way too slow. The benchmarks on C file smoke iostream

Comment: "Append" means to append i.e. at last of a file. They trail, they do not lead. Try using "a+" mode.

Comment: What would be the proper approach to re-access the file at a specific byte?

Comment: Okay thanks. I give that a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the way that hard drives and filesystems work, inserting bytes in to the middle of a file is really slow and should be avoided, especially when dealing with multi-gigabyte files. If your metadata is stored in to a fixed-size header, just make sure that there's enough space for it before you start with the other data. If the header is variably sized, then chunk up the header. Put 1k of header space at the beginning, and have 8 bytes reserved to contain the value of the offset to the next header chunk, or 0 for EOF. Then when that chunk gets filled up, just add another chunk to the end of the file and write its offset to the previous header.

As for the technical IO, use the `fopen()` modes of `r+b`, `w+b`, or `a+b`, depending on your need. They all act the same with minor differences. `r+b` opens the file for reading and writing, starting at the first byte. It will error if the file doesn't exist. `w+b` will do the same, but create the file if it doesn't exist. `a+b` is the same as `r+b`, but it starts with the file pointer at the end of the file.

You can navigate the file with `fseek()` and `rewind()`. `rewind()` moves the file pointer back to the beginning of the file. `fseek()` moves the file pointer to a specified location. You can read more about it [here.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fseek/)

Comment: a+b not the same as r+b. If file not exists, a+b will create it, r+b will fail. Also a+b positions the file at the start for reading, but all writes are added to end of file. [See here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/)

Comment: Okay. I only need to append the beginning of the file a couple of times with header information. Once I get to the code that actually processes the numerical data , it's all sequential, and I won't be trying to access anything out of sequence. When I finish, I may have to add some final header info. Thats it.

Comment: Thank You @Alec Danyshchuk; The docs you provided a link to clearly state the only mode that will do what I'm trying to do is "r+" or "r+b".

Comment: C++ Reference: says for "w+"  
"If a file with the same name already exists its contents are discarded and the file is treated as a new empty file."
So it is another difference with "a+"

Answer (score 1):

"r+b" means you can read and write to any position in the file. In your second code block the rewind() call set the current position to byte 0 and the write is done at this position.

If you use "a+b", this also means read and write access, but the writes are all at the end of the file so you cannot position at byte 0, unless a new empty file is created.

To re-access the file at a specific byte, just use fseek().

fseek ( fileStream , 0  , SEEK_SET ); - positions to the precision value

fseek ( fileStream , 4  , SEEK_SET ); - positions to the year      value

fseek ( fileStream , 8  , SEEK_SET ); - positions to the month     value

fseek ( fileStream , 12 , SEEK_SET ); - positions to the day       value

Answer (score 0):

With such large files, it would be highly inefficient to rewrite gigs just to prepend a few bytes.

It would be much better to create a small companion file of the metadata you need for each file, and only add the metadata fields to the beginning of the files if they are to be rewritten anyway as part of an edit.

This is because prepending to a file is so expensive on most file systems.
NTFS has a second data channel for most files that goes unseen by almost all programs except for MS internals such as file managers and security scanning programs. You could easily cook up  a program to add your metadata to that channel without needing to overwrite gigs  on disk every single time.